# Omitting or leaving "\n" prints "Hello world" twice in using fork()

Tags: c, process, fork

I am using gcc compiler on linux.

When I run this code (Notice"\n" is not present after hello world in printf)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world");
    fork();
}
```

I GET THIS OUTPUT: Hello worldHello world

On the other hand
When I run this code (Notice"\n" is present after hello world in printf)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    fork();
}
```

I GET THIS OUTPUT: Hello world

Can someone describe in detail that, why omitting or leaving "\n" prints "Hello world"  twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having the `\n` means that "hello world" is still in memory - ready to go one its merry way to the terminal.

`fork` will make a duplicate of this memory - i.e. now you have two processes with the same "hello world" in memory. When the program terminates it will flush this to stdout. I.e. getting it twice.

But if you put the `\n` in - it gets flush to stdout immediately. Hence this buffer will be empty before the `fork` is called.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on the answer in the linked question and relate it to your question, `stdout` generally buffers input until it sees a `\n`, or you explicitly `fflush` it.

When you have the `\n` there, you are making it flush before the `fork()`. 
Without the `\n`, it flushes **after** the fork, so it will exist in both processes.

In the linked question, they talk about `fflush()`, but `\n` has the same effect of causing `stdout` to flush.

You will see only one print with the program below as well:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world");
    fflush(stdout);
    fork();
}
```

**Edit:** Due to a comment from Dabo, `\n` will only cause a flush if `stdout` is in line buffering mode instead of full buffering mode. We can observe in the following program that we still see the string printed twice, even with `\n`, when full buffering mode is turned on using [`setvbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL,_IOFBF, BUFSIZ);
    printf("Hello world\n");
    fork();
}
```

Output:

```
Hello world
Hello world
```

Comment: The last paragraph in the first answer in the linked question explains why `\n` changes the behavior.

Comment: @Barmar, Oops, I didn't read down far enough. Should I delete this answer or leave it for others who decide to google for `\n` and fork?

Comment: Leave it, it's helpful to reinforce concepts

Comment: @Dabo, Thank you. I have updated the answer with your note.

Comment: @merlin2011 +1, but i still decided to add my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say both versions are incorrect. The C runtime will register [`atexit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) handlers to flush standard buffers when [`exit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit) is called. The proper way to cause your program print only once is to call [`_exit(0);`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit) in child process. This way your child won't call [`atexit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) ( which in turn won't flush buffers twice)

```
if (fork() == 0)
    _exit(0);
```